# How to make a docker-compose exec return the return value of the command?

Tags: bash, docker-compose

When I write this in a bash script:

```
docker-compose exec -T cli curl http://nginx:8080 -v

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo "OK!"
else
  echo "FAIL"
  /bin/false
fi
```

No matter if the page is a HTTP 200 OK or if it's a HTTP 503 Internal Server Error, both will return value 0 (success).

How can I build around this?

Comment: I can't reproduce your behavior, when I try running `docker-compose exec -T pgadmin curl http://example.com -v` then $? equal 7. pgadmin happen to be a service I have in a project but it should be the same from any service. can you share your compose file/dockerfiles so I can try reproducing it in the exact same context please ?